# Would it be advisable to have the routes.rb look through directories when creating routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I have a controller called 'reports'.  In it, I want to display pre-made reports through partials.  As it stands, I don't want to make a fully-fledged sql query/report generator so I figure the easiest way to do this is that every time I want to make a new report, I do so only in a partial file.  I then upload that file and all the routes/methods are generated on the fly.  That means that there is a method in the controller that looks through the views directory for partials and then returns a url-safe string to be used in the routes and in the controller models.

The question I have is "would this produce a bottleneck in speed"?  Such that every time a url is requested, the directory is searched.

Controller:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController

    def initialize
    super()
    ReportsController::reports(true).each do |report|
        self.class.send(:define_method, report.gsub('-', '_').to_sym) do
        render "#{name_to_safe_url(report).gsub('-', '_')}.html.erb"
        end
    end
    end

    # Currently I'm just using a static array to give the reports.
    # This will change such that it will look through the views directory
    # for partials.  It will read the file name and return it as part of the list
    def self.reports(return_url = false)
    list = [
        "Revenue/Sale",
        "Item Quantities",
        "Number of Sales/Day",
        "Compare Revenue to Past Dates"
    ]
    return_url ? list.map{|i| name_to_safe_url(i)} : list
    end

    def self.name_to_safe_url(name)
    name.gsub(/\//, ' per ').squeeze(' ').gsub(/[^a-z]/i, '-').squeeze('-').chomp('-').downcase
    end

end
```

Comment: umm yeah.. I wouldn't do it this way. I would model the Report and store the template in a text field field. Also, store a 'slug', the url safe name  as a field in the same model. The route would have a slug parameter that the controller would use to lookup the report record and use Erubis to render the markup for insertion into the layout. my 2 cents

Comment: After reading what you've said, I've decided to go with using paperclip to store the partial along with everything else you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Please repeat the [Skinny Controller Fat Model](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model) mantra before writing code like this.

Comment: OK; so I move all of that to my model.  Do you have an answer to my question?